# true or false if n is an odd integer with n>3, then σ(n) is less than or equal to σ(n-1)

Tags: number-theory

If this is true, i need to provide a proof, and if it is false, i need to provide a counter example. I don't know where to begin on how to prove or disprove this since number theory is definitely a weak spot for me

Comment: What exactly does $\sigma$ denote in this context? I can think of a few different ways it was used in my elementary number theory text.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: presumably the sum of divisors function, since $\sigma(3)=4 \not \le 3=\sigma(2)$

Answer (score 0):

It is false:

$$\sigma(63)=1+3+7+9+21+63 = 104$$

while $$\sigma(62)=1+2+31+62=96$$

and $104 \not \le 96$